# Wrapping column text in an apex panel grid so that the table width remains fixed

Tags: apex, visualforce, css, html

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="4" width="100%" columnClasses="random" >
<apex:repeat value="{!ProcessCellValuesWithoutName}" var="strCellValue">

<apex:outputLabel rendered="{!(!strCellValue.renderLink)}">{!strCellValue.recValues}</apex:outputLabel>
<apex:outputLabel rendered="{!(!strCellValue.renderLink)}">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</apex:outputLabel>

</apex:repeat>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

I have tried adding style class to outputlabel and use the css properties like `word-break:break-word/break-all` , but that does not seem to wrap the column text when its too long to the next line and maintain the table width.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put the labels inside an `apex:outputPanel` in order to render the cells needed for proper wrapping to take place.

```
<apex:panelGrid columns="4" width="100%" columnClasses="random">
    <apex:repeat value="{!ProcessCellValuesWithoutName}" var="strCellValue">

        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(!strCellValue.renderLink)}">
            {!strCellValue.recValues}
        </apex:outputPanel>
        <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(!strCellValue.renderLink)}">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:repeat>
</apex:panelGrid>
```

This is because labels are `inline` elements, but you need `tr` and `td` elements for the table to render properly. If you need additional formatting, do so inside the `apex:outputPanel` elements.

Comment: Thanks a lot sfdcfox ! That works. But the same css does not work when the page is rendered as pdf using the renderAs="pdf" attribute on <apex:page>

Comment: @paritoshparimal Make sure the styles are in the `<head>` tag, not the body, and are properly formatted. The CSS renderer in the PDF mode is kind of a pain to work with, as it doesn't support many common styles and properties.